# telerik ASP.net MVC Grid Ajax binding issue

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, binding, telerik

I compared the codes with [Telerik sample](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/ajaxbinding) , everything is the same except the model. But I can't see the records in Grid.

```
// Controller
  public  ActionResult Index()
    {
           return View();
    } 
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult _Index()
    {
        return View(new GridModel<AuctionViewModel>
                    {
                     Data = GetData()
                    }
                   );
    }
```

// If I replace 'Index' Action codes with '_Index' , the server binding works fine and shows the records but when I try to run AjaxBinding , It doesn't works (never runs _Index codes)

// View

```
    @model List<TestMVC3_Telerik.Models.AuctionViewModel>
    @{      
    Html.Telerik().Grid((List<TestMVC3_Telerik.Models.AuctionViewModel>)ViewData["MyAuctions"])
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.AuctionID).Title("ID").Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.AuctionName).Title("Name");
    })
      .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_Index", "Grid"))
    .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(5))
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Filterable();
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you try to page? Does the grid page using server binding?

Comment: An empty grid appears. I can change the codes in order to use server binding and it works, but my problem is I can't use Ajax binding.

Comment: The code looks ok. I suggest you prepare a sample project and send it as an attachment to the Telerik forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_Index", "Grid"))

Change "Grid" to what you are calling the page from

.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_Index", "Home"))

Once I did that it loaded for me.